# How to add dynamic properties into the input element based on condition?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Following are the snippet of the two input element which will be loaded based on the condition?
There is one name props and based on the value of props it will load the input.

Here if the name contains the some value then it will load first input with the property **maxlength="10"** and rest of the property will remain same.

Here my question how to optimize the code so it will remove the one input element,I want only one input element.

Any help would be great.

```js
const name = {this.props}
{ name === "xyz" ?

<input
   type={type || 'text'}
   name={name}
   onBlur={onBlur}
   onChange={onChange}
   onDragStart={onDragStart}
   onDrop={onDrop}
   onFocus={onFocus}
   maxlength="10"
   value={value}
   disabled={disabled}
   className={[className, disabled ? 'disabled' : ''].join(' ')}
   placeholder={placeholder}
   min={min}
 />
:

<input
   type={type || 'text'}
   name={name}
   onBlur={onBlur}
   onChange={onChange}
   onDragStart={onDragStart}
   onDrop={onDrop}
   onFocus={onFocus}
   value={value}
   disabled={disabled}
   className={[className, disabled ? 'disabled' : ''].join(' ')}
   placeholder={placeholder}
   min={min}
 />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work

```js
const name = {this.props}
<input
   type={type || 'text'}
   name={name}
   onBlur={onBlur}
   onChange={onChange}
   onDragStart={onDragStart}
   onDrop={onDrop}
   onFocus={onFocus}
   {...name==='xyz' && {maxlength:"10"}}
   value={value}
   disabled={disabled}
   className={[className, disabled ? 'disabled' : ''].join(' ')}
   placeholder={placeholder}
   min={min}
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
...

function App() {
  const name = "abc";
  ...

  const attribs = {
    type: type || "text",
    name: name,
    ...
    className: [className, disabled ? "disabled" : ""].join(" "),
    ...
  };

  if (name === "xyz") {
    attribs["maxLength"] = "10";
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input {...attribs} />
    </div>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```